# What explains the angled stripes of mineral visible on the side of some islands?

Tags: geology, mineralogy, minerals

I was exploring some islands by boat recently and I came upon some pretty impressive rock formation. I'm interested in finding what mechanism produces those angle mineral strips. Some of them were a couple inches wide, others some feet wide. They were angled at around 45 degrees creating lines all across the side of the island. (Which was 25 to 30m high) [image: The strip on the left of the image] I tried doing a research on Google but being unfamiliar with the terms of geology, I couldn't orient my search properly. Does anybody could point me to some articles or terms to help me research the subject or provide a quick explanation as to what causes those minerals to be aligned at those angles?[image]

The pictures aren't the best but you can see on the left of the first one the mineral strip and a smaller one on the second picture.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide some information about the location? It would help to know the geological setting. It could be [veins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vein_(geology)) or it could be [dikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dike_(geology)).

Comment: This is the island:
https://maps.app.goo.gl/NaSYTSuBFgUKqu8C9